# C# Serialization and DataContracts

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a situation that I can't figure out. I have two object classes:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Instrument
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string Id {get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool HideMe {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Code {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string OrderId {get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Instrument Inst {get; set;}
}
```

My code tries to serialize a JSON message of Orders. I can see in the JSON string that instrument data exists but the serialized order objects contain blank Instrument objects.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can you post the Json and the call site?

Comment: You don't need two attributes - [DataContract] and [DataMember] inherit from Serializable. Remove [Serializable] attribute and try again.
Also please show your serialization code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] showing how you are serializing and deserializing the `Order` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. The issue was that I hadn't rebuilt and released the windows service that sends the JSON.